# How to export in CSV with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I using this function to export a data range in CSV:

```
Sub Fct_Export_CSV()
  Dim Value As String
  Dim size As Integer

  Value = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Export_" & Sheets(1).range("B20").Value & ".csv"
  chemincsv = Value

  Worksheets("Database").Select
  Dim Plage As Object, oL As Object, oC As Object, Tmp As String, Sep$
  Sep = ";"
  size = Worksheets("Database").range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set Plage = ActiveSheet.range("A1:G" & size)

  Open chemincsv For Output As #1
  For Each oL In Plage.Rows
    Tmp = ""
    For Each oC In oL.Cells
      Tmp = Tmp & CStr(oC.Text) & Sep
    Next
    Print #1, Tmp
  Next
  Close

  MsgBox "OK! Export to " & Value
End Sub
```

Export works but i have one too ";" at the end of each line.

Example export CSV:

> Folder;Tree;Group;FirstName;LastName;sAMAccountName;Rules;
>   FOLDER;TREE;DL-FOLDER-R;John;TOTO;JTOT;R;

Where do i modify this VBA script to generate a CSV without ";" at the end ? 

My goal:

> Folder;Tree;Group;FirstName;LastName;sAMAccountName;Rules
>   FOLDER;TREE;DL-FOLDER-R;John;TOTO;JTOT;R

Comment: Some tips for your code: Dim chemincsv (if it isn't already dimmed globally); don't `.Select` the worksheet, just use the `Worksheet("Database")` instead of `ActiveSheet`; `Dim` all your ranges as `Range`; don't name a variable `range` (I suspect you did somewhere because it's not capitalized in your code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.
For eg. you could put a if condition in `Tmp = Tmp & CStr(oC.Text) & Sep` to not append sep if the iteration is the last one.

Another way would be to use left function. Without modifying much of your code, I think this would be a good approach.
Here is a sample code(havnt tried):

```
Sub Fct_Export_CSV()
  Dim Value As String
  Dim size As Integer

  Value = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Export_" & Sheets(1).range("B20").Value & ".csv"
  chemincsv = Value

  Worksheets("Database").Select
  Dim Plage As Object, oL As Object, oC As Object, Tmp As String, Sep$
  Sep = ";"
  size = Worksheets("Database").range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set Plage = ActiveSheet.range("A1:G" & size)

  Open chemincsv For Output As #1
  For Each oL In Plage.Rows
    Tmp = ""
    For Each oC In oL.Cells
      Tmp = Tmp & CStr(oC.Text) & Sep
    Next


'take one less than length of the string number of characters from left, that would eliminate the trailing semicolon
    Tmp = left(Tmp, Len(Tmp)-1)

    Print #1, Tmp
  Next
  Close



  MsgBox "OK! Export to " & Value
End Sub
```

Added one line of code before the last print statement, should work. lemme know.

Comment: Hi, Please accept the answer, if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you work on a machine that has the semicolon set as local separator you can save the sheet as csv and specify `Local:=True`

```
Worksheets("Database").SaveAs Filename:=Value, FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
```